# How to get arg0 from _start() implementation?

Tags: c++, c, runtime

I need to implement my `_start()` function in C, so I can manage my own global constructors and call my `main()` function as I want.

My problem is when I have to get command line arguments and the `argc` value. Some time ago I saw something like this using an `arg0` value which should point to the first arg:

```
extern int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);

void _start() {
  // calling all the global ctors here

  exit(main(/* something i don't rememebr as argc */, &arg0));
}
```

How can I get that `arg0`? And how do I get the `argc` value from the command line?

**UPDATE:**
With "global constructors" I mean functions which initializes any global variable. Like `int x = doit();` the call to function `doit()` is enclosed in a global constructor which will be called before `main` (in the `_start()` actually).

Comment: Totally depends on how the OS is providing the arguments to the process. If you don't have an OS, just provide `argc` as `0` and `argv` as `NULL`.

Comment: How can I figure out what value I should use for each OS? Is there something which explains it? Like a list or something like that

Comment: Providing a `_start` at all is not portable in the first place. Good luck making it work for every OS.

Comment: This is not for the weak of heart. Imagine the multitutde of tasks you need to perform in _start! Calling constructors is just of them. How about binding dynamic objects?

Comment: You are deep into compiler-specific stuff. What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @osnapitzkindle May be [this](http://learningpearls.blogspot.de/2011/02/start-function-inside-c.html) helps a bit.

Comment: I'm writing a compiler and I need to write the runtime library my programs will link against. It's just normal it's not portable lol, providing a _start for each platform is not a problem. I already knew it and I'll definitely do it. I just need to know if I can maybe write it in C just to try before writing it in assembly for each platform.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sounds like the OP want's to solve the static initialization fiasko.

Comment: @osnapitzkindle - okay, so you're legitimately deep into compiler-specific stuff. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, I'm developing a new language and I'm really interested in such things